# Find all paths between two nodes using DFS in weighted directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I had a **directed weighted** graph **G**, where weight is duration of transition.

I wrote all paths search algorithm between two vertices using DFS with modification: the search continues until total weight of path (the sum of the weights of its parts) will be less some value.

My code works in small graph, but in big graph (|V|=1800, |E|=50870) it freezes.

```
def find_paths(self, start, end, weight_limit=10):
        res = []

        def dfs(start, end, path=[], weight=0):
            path = path + [start]
            if len(path) > 1:
                weight += self.weights[(path[-2], start)]
            if weight > weight_limit:
                return []
            if start == end:
                res.append((path, weight))
                return [path]
            if start not in self.adjacent:
                return []
            paths = []
            for node in self.adjacent[start]:
                if node not in path:
                    paths.extend(dfs(node, end, path, weight))
            return paths

        dfs(start, end)
        return res
```

Comment: Might be a memory error. Do you actually need to keep track of all the paths and their weights?

Comment: @JaredGoguen Yes I need to keep track of all the paths and their weights, because my goal is find ALL paths between START and END nodes in my GRAPH. So, if it is a memory error, is it possible solution to fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: The total number of paths might grow factorially with the number of edges. Even 50! is too large to be approached by enumeration, never mind 50000!.

Comment: @JaredGoguen so, its impossible task to solve? I mean find all path between START and END in this graph with total_weight < certain value?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct (especially since it works on small graphs).

The problem is that there can be lots of paths between the nodes. For a fully connected graph the number of paths is on the order of N! which is a lot. Since you need all of them your program is going to be slow (especially if you run out of ram and need to swap things to disk).

If you limit the maximum total weight like you did in your code assuming all weights are one you still run in O(weight), which I assume you set to a large value since the graph is large.

You need to figure out if you really need all those paths.

If you are looking for the shortest path use Dijkstra or something for finding the shortest path.

Comment: To elaborate on "Dijkstra or something" http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2942/am-i-right-about-the-differences-between-floyd-warshall-dijkstra-and-bellman-fo

Comment: @Sorin no, I need all paths between two nodes (without cycles). And I needn't to find shortest paths, I need to find path with total_weight < certain value